# Select multiple check boxes by clicking the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table with many check boxes. If I select the first check box, the next one is automatically selected.  Does someone know how to do this? Also, the exact row number in table is unknown.

```js
function toggle(source) {
  var row_index = $("#checkFirst").index();
  var row_first = $(".row").index();
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('row');

  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == row_index && i == row_first) {
      checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: list">
  <tr>

    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkFirst" onClick="toggle(this)" /></td>

    <td><input type="checkbox" name="row"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>

  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for this. First give class checkbox to all other checkboxes. Hope this can help you

```
$(function(){

$("#checkFirst").click(function () {
      $('.checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

$(".checkbox").click(function(){

    if($(".checkbox").length == $(".checkbox:checked").length) {
        $("#checkFirst").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#checkFirst").removeAttr("checked");
    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this makes the first checkbox a global control for all

```js
$('#checkFirst').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
  else
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: list">
<tr>

<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkFirst"/></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="row"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>

</tr>

</tbody>
```

and this is to select the following checkboxes in the same row

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){
    $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: This selects all checkboxes, as well as throws an error because `toggle()` is not defined.

Comment: @chrisz lol, the toggle is in the op's code. I'll remove it. doesn't the OP want all the checkboxes ? hmm

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code. It will help you.

jQuery file: 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: list">
<tr id="first">

<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkfirst" onClick="toggle('first',this.id)"/></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="row"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="row"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="row"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="row"></td>

</tr>
<tr id="second">

<td><input type="checkbox" id="checksecond" onClick="toggle('second',this.id)"/></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" ></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Script

```
<script>
function toggle(source,id) {
chcked = $('#'+id).prop( "checked" );
if(chcked)
{
  $('#'+source+' :checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;                        
    });
}
else
{
     $('#'+source+' :checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;                        
    });
}  
}
</script>
```

Comment: It works only for first row and selects all checkboxes

Comment: i can't. I'm getting rows based on "data-bind="foreach: list", so i don't know how many rows i will have

Comment: It's not a problem, add Ids for rows and first checkbox of row dynamically.

Example:
foreach($values as $val)
    {
     $i++;

     ?>
     <tr id="first<?php echo $i;?>">
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="check<?php echo $i;?>" onClick="toggle('first<?php echo $i;?>',this.id)"/></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="row"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="row"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="row"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="row"></td>
  </tr>
     <?php
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet.

```
function handleCheck(e) {
    let will_change = false;
    if (e.shiftKey && this.checked) {
        checkboxes.forEach(element => {
            if (element === this || element === last_checked) {
                will_change = !will_change;
            }
            if (will_change) {
                element.checked = true;
            }
        });
    }
    last_checked = this;
}
```

Then add a click event listener to each of the checkboxes you want to act as a group

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyQEJZ